# Axios get data based on token passed from frontend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios, vuex

Can you guys help me? I've been trying to get the **token** I placed as a parameter from the URL in Axios (Yes, the **ID** is also included in the URL BUT it is **static** for the if else condition at the backend). I tried cheating the Request Methods but it won't work since if a method is set as POST, then it just stays as POST. It won't GET or DELETE or UPDATE anything else. Tried file_get_contents as well but since it's not POST, then it won't read it. Also tried the other answers from stackoverflow but they don't have the backend parts.

index.js

```
findSub ({ commit }, payload) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios
            .get('http://localhost/MyComposer/?id=00', {
              params: {
                token: this.state.token
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
              resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject(error)
            })
        })
      },
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'Classes/Headers.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Classes\SubjectClass;
use Classes\TestClass;
use Classes\AnswerClass;
use Classes\LoginClass;
use Classes\TeacherClass;
use Classes\AccountClass;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $addsubject = new SubjectClass();
    $addsubject->addSubject();
    $addtest = new TestClass();
    $addtest->addTest();
    $submitTest = new AnswerClass();
    $submitTest->submitTest();
    $submitLoginData = new LoginClass();
    $submitLoginData->submitLoginData();
    $addTeacher = new TeacherClass();
    $addTeacher->addTeacher();
    $findSub = new TeacherClass();
    $findSub->findSub();
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $subOptions = new SubjectClass();
    $subOptions->getSubName();
    $testOptions = new TestClass();
    $testOptions->getTest();
    $accountOp = new AccountClass();
    $accountOp->getAccount();
}
```

SubjectClass.php

```
public function getSubName {
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] === 'id=00') {
            $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $tokenId = json_decode($data);
            $token = $tokenId->{'token'};

            $db->where('AccessId', $access_id);
            $subId5 = $db->get('accounts');

            if ($subId5) {
                echo json_encode($subId5);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['token']`?

Comment: Okay, I admit that I made an error with my question. It's actually the TOKEN that I wanted my backend to receive, NOT the ID. The ID that is inside the URL is static.

Comment: Axios puts the values from `params` in the query string so your PHP should be able to access the token via `$_GET['token']`

Comment: Just $_GET['token']? I don't need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)...

> `params` are the **URL parameters** to be sent with the request

Axios is able to merge any query parameters in the URL (ie `?id=00`) with the `params` object. With the client-side code you're using, this would result in a `GET` request to

> `http://localhost/MyComposer/?id=00&token=some-token-value`

No matter the request type, PHP accesses query parameters via the `$_GET` super-global array. This means that as long as you're using

```js
params: { token: someTokenValue }
```

for a `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` or whatever request method, PHP can access the token via

```php
$token = $_GET['token'] ?? null; // or whatever makes sense as a default
```

---

A little advice for your JS code...

1. You've fallen into the all-too-common explicit promise construction anti-pattern. Axios already returns a promise so you can just use that.
2. You should be accessing `state` from the `context` parameter passed in to your action, not `this.state`
3. I wouldn't mix query parameters in the URL and `params`. The latter is much easier and encodes values correctly

```js
findSub: ({ state }) => axios.get('http://localhost/MyComposer/', {
  params: {
    id: '00',
    token: state.token
  }
})
```

Comment: I forgot to include an Axios.post method that I made for the frontend. Should I POST the token or let it remain as a parameter for GET?

Comment: @Codebuddy7 like I said in my answer, if you're using query parameters or the `params` config in Axios, the values will be available to PHP in `$_GET` no matter what request method you use

Comment: Where you put your token (in the URL / in the request body / as a request header) is up to you. It's your application

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Update: It works. Thanks for using your time helping me. All I can do is give a hidden upvote on your answer and hope others would do the same.

Comment: @Codebuddy7 You're welcome. I'm not sure what a _"hidden upvote"_ is but if this answer helped, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)